# Get part of element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting the number part of the container ID that the button is in. Now I am wondering if I need to create an array using `split` and then put this number in a variable, or if there is a more efficient way to get it.

[`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) also returns an array, so this is almost the same as using split.

I mean the code works and it's ok, but I'm curious to see if there is a better way.

```js
 $('.add').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var $this = $(this);
   var tab_number_array = $this.parents('.tab_content').attr('id').split('_');
   var tab_number = tab_number_array[1];
   alert(tab_number);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="tab_1" class="tab_content">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="add">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab_2" class="tab_content">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="add">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab_3" class="tab_content">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="add">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`parents`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) method will traverse the DOM all the way up the chain. Rather use the [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method, which will stop at the first match:

```
$('.add').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var number = $(this).closest('.tab_content').attr('id').split('_')[1];

    alert(number);
});
```

Comment: I'll try this one. I haven't used `.closest`before so I didn't know about it, but from the little reading I did, this does optimize the code ([reference](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquerys-closest-parents/)). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Now I am wondering if I need to create an array using `split` and then put this number in a variable, or if there is a more efficient way to get it.

This all depends on what you are doing with the value.

if you are just going to alert the value, like you are in the originally posted code, then there is no reason to create a variable just to alert it immediately afterwards. no real good reason to `var $this = $(this);` either, it's an extra step that makes the code messy.

A much simpler looking code that says exactly what it is doing.

```
$('.add').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tab_number_array = $(this).parents('.tab_content').attr('id').split('_');
    alert(tab_number_array[1]);
});
```

I might even go as far as just alerting the output instead of assigning to a variable and the alerting the variable, the only reason I would do it the way that you are doing it in the original post is because it is going to be a little simpler to debug and see what the value is while debugging. But, if you have it nailed down, go ahead and shorten it up.

---

> [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
>   also returns an array, so this is almost the same as using split.

Match uses a regular expression, which you obviously don't need here, you are just taking the elements ID, splitting on a delimiter and taking the second part, I would say that a regex would muddy the waters. I wouldn't use match, I would use the split like you are currently doing.

Comment: I need the variable so that I can use it for a counting purposes, the snippet I put up is just the excerpt. I need just the number from the id's (which I'll later use), and was wandering if there is a more direct way then creating an array and then using the array value later on. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: if you need that variable to store the number then chances are you are going to call a function inside this event or you create the variable elsewhere.  we can't review code that isn't here, so many things could be different depending on the code that isn't given here.  next time include more code in your question, you will get better reviews

Comment: Oh, ok, but I was just interested in the split issue, the rest of the code works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

If there is a provision of changing HTML, you can add `data-id` and directly access it as `$(this).parent().data("id");`

I prefer using `data` attribute as they keep code clean.

Also if are manipulating element multiple times then having `$this` makes sense. If not, you can get rid of it.

```js
$('.add').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var tab_number = $(this).parents('.tab_content').data('id');
  alert(tab_number);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="tab_1" data-id="1" class="tab_content">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="add">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab_2" data-id="2" class="tab_content">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="add">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab_3" data-id="3" class="tab_content">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="add">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using $this, because of multiple references in the code :) Also I didn't want to add even more attributes, but it's a good solution, I agree.